# "1st arg. contains undefined in property 'users.undefined.email ' " and if i write "object." twice it works fine why is that?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

```
    signup(event){
        const email=this.refs.email.value;
        const password=this.refs.password.value;

        const auth = firebase.auth();

        const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
        promise
        .then(user => {
          var err= "Welcome "+ user.email; //if i write user.user.email here it works fine
          firebase.database().ref('users/'+ user.uid).set({
          email : user.email //if i write user.user.email here it works fine
         });
```

why at times we have to write "object.object.something" instead of "object.something" in react js?
it displays a error(users.undefined.email in the firebase.database() line  is undefined) when i run this code

Comment: Isn't it just that the firebase response is structured that way? `response.user.email` seams reasonable to me.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the docs, but [`createUserWithEmailAndPassword` seem to return a `firebase.auth.UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword) which [has a `user` key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#.UserCredential).

Comment: No you were right, i just got confused with something....sorry for that and thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note, that 'user' in

```
.then( user => {
```

is just a synonym. You could name it 'response', 'cat' or somewhat else.

If you print it's structure with `console.log()` you‘ll see that it looks like this

```
{
    user: {
                  email: xyz@xyz.com,
                  name: username
                  ...
            }
}
```

So you have to pass 2 levels until you reach the wanted content. Rename 'user' into 'response' to make it obvious, what‘s going here:

```
response.user.email
```